# How to generate new var names on the fly

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable-substitution

I'm trying to generate dynamic var names in a shell script to process a set of files with distinct names in a loop as follows:

```
SAMPLE1='1-first.with.custom.name'
SAMPLE2='2-second.with.custom.name'

for (( i = 1; i <= 2; i++ ))
do
  echo SAMPLE{$i}
done
```

I would expect the output:

```
1-first.with.custom.name
2-second.with.custom.name
```

but i got:

```
SAMPLE{1}
SAMPLE{2}
```

Is it possible generate var names in the fly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use an array, they're meant for doing things like that.

```
sample[1]='1-first.with.custom.name'
sample[2]='2-second.with.custom.name'

for (( i = 1; i <= 2; i++ ))
do
  echo ${sample[$i]}
done
```

Also don't use all-capital variable names in your script to prevent accidentally using reserved variable names.

Comment: Mainly because that was the first idea coming to my mind and needed quickly do a test. Arrays are more flexible and I will take them into account for future works

Comment: arrays don't work on bash 3 (which is on my macbook for example)

Answer (score 5):

I found that I can get the expected results as follows:

```
for (( i = 1; i <= 2; i++ ))
do
  NEW_NAME=SAMPLE$i
  echo ${!NEW_NAME}
done
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it using portable, POSIX standard shell and avoid bash extensions like arrays, you need to use eval:

```
$ foo1='a b c'
$ foo2='d e f'
$ a=1; eval echo \$foo$a
a b c
$ a=2; eval echo \$foo$a
d e f
```

Comment: Actually, It is a test case for personal use but thanks for the advice on make it portable.